# Can ffmpeg support creating DASH "availabilityStartTime" with milliseconds?

Tags: ffmpeg, mpeg-dash, dash

I'm currently trying to use FFMpeg to capture my webcam , output it to dash and stream it live.
I noticed that the "availabilityStartTime" parameter created in the MPD file is without the milliseconds part.

> availabilityStartTime="2018-12-31T14:47:13Z"

I noticed that the ffmpeg library use "get_utc_date_time_insec" to fill the availabilityStartTime in the MPD file.

Is there a way for ffmpeg to fill the availabilityStartTime with complete timestamp?

Thank you

Comment: Not implemented, but it could be added to the code. But why would you need such precision here?

Comment: ffmpeg is using ISO-8601 format for date time. Although not specified anywhere in the DASH spec (ISO 23009), all examples use the 8601 format. So it's unlikely that this would be changed.

Comment: We need this information to be as precised as possible as we count on the availabilityStartTime for synchronization between two live streams.

Comment: @Gyan DASH uses XML's `xs:dateTime` for timing, which *can* use millisecond precision. But it's unlikely that this is needed in practice.

Comment: @slhck I agree with you , however we do have a case where the extra milliseconds data is important for us.
If the Dash spec does not conflict with the ffmpeg implementation (meaning that the complete timestamp can be used)  , why not adding it?

Comment: Sure, I agree it wouldn't hurt to have if the spec allows it, but as I'm not a core FFmpeg developer, I don't know if changing the assumption that these timings can have millisecond precision carries all sorts of other changes with it. In principle you could patch the function `format_date_now` in `dashenc.c` to return milliseconds.

Comment: @slhck thank you , we did a custom patch to ffmpeg like you said and its working now

Comment: For anyone that may be interested in this feature too , It's already in FFMPEG main. - https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/commit/b6d96a6bcc531c216623fbcdf9d5034f51abf216#diff-bb639d36d2c5d7cdcefacb6273d80d1f